# Building a text string from date details in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, date

I've hunted around and found plenty of ways to convert a string to a date, but I can't seem to find one for the reverse... so here we go.

I'm trying to build a text string for a query, specifically running through WordPress on MySQL, for the BAW Post Count plugin data. That plugin uses a meta-key which always begins the same (*count-views*) and is followed by 'day', 'month' and so on, then the date part.

What I want to do is specify which meta-key I'm looking for by building a text string based on the current date:

"_count-views_month-" then the 4-figure year and two-figure month. 
For example, this month is October 2013, so it would come out as "_count-views_month-201310"

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to get the year and month as text, for use in a php script.

I've tried using `year(now()),year(date(now()))`, `cast`, `concat` and a variety of other things but none seem to work. I know it must be incredibly easy and I'm just complicating matters or overlooking something obvious, but I can't see what!

So, the question is how I can do that as a `"$variable="` statement, please.

Thanks!

Comment: PHP version ? Below examples run good in PHP 5.4 and above. Its different syntax for php 5.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You over-thought it:

```
echo date("Ym"); // outputs "201310"
```

Full example:

```
echo '_count-views_month-' . date("Ym");
```

Or:

```
printf("_count-views_month-%s", date("Ym"));
```

Or, in SQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT("_count-views_month-", DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, "%Y%m"))
```

Comment: Thanks, John... that's wonderful. I knew I was trying too hard but just couldn't see it. $thismonth='_count-views_month-' . date("Ym"); does the job perfectly.